# Redux query returning undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm having this problem with redux where I run one api service and the response is received fine. However after I add another reducer path `reducer:{ [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer, },`
my response for all other services becomes undefined. Even if I return to only one reducer path from that point on all requests return undefined.
[photo of response found in the network section of the consul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOJY2.png)

[photo of second response from the same api found in the consul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXNu4.png)

Does anyone know what's going on?

Api service setup

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";
const cryptoHeaders = {
  'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
  'X-RapidAPI-Key': '9f2533afaemsh1f8a925387397f8p1fea4ejsn485665c91539'
};
const baseUrl =  "https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com";
const createRequest= (url) => ({
  url,
  headers:cryptoHeaders
})
export const cryptoApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "crytopApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl}),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getCryptoData: builder.query({
      query: () => createRequest(`/coins`),
    }),
  }),
});

export const {useGetCryptoDataQuery} = cryptoApi
```

Where I'm calling it from

```
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { useGetCryptoDataQuery } from "./services/cryptoApi";
import { useGetnewsDataQuery } from "./services/newsApi";
import "./app.css";
const App = () => {
  const { cryptoData, cryptoError, isLoadingCrypto } = useGetCryptoDataQuery();
  console.log(cryptoData)
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(cryptoData)}</div>;
};

export default App;
```

store setup

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import { cryptoApi } from '../services/cryptoApi'
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer:{
        [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
    },
})
```

I do call a provider and pass in the store

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { store } from "./store/store.js";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import App from "./App.jsx";
import "./index.css";
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you're adding another reducer with the same function name. Your store is like this:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
       [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
       [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer
    }
})
```

Instead it should be like this:

```
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
       [cryptoApi.reducerPath]:cryptoApi.reducer,
       [cryptoNewsApi.reducerPath]:cryptoNewsApi.reducer
    }
})
```